# Selenium Timing issue: form fields are not filled correctly

Tags: selenium, clojure

I am using [clj-webdriver](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver) to fill out a form in my test case.

```
(quick-fill-submit {"#firstname" "Firstnam"}
                   {"#lastname"  "Lastnaem"}
                   {"#username"  "Username"}
                   {"#password"  "Password"}
                   {"#password2" "Password"}
                   {"#roles"     "user"})

(click "button#add-user")
```

Every time I run this code in my test case the third value is filled in blank.
I moved the fields around and verified it. It is always the third field.

When execute my test case step by step in a repl it works fine but when
running it through `lein test` it fails.

This seems to be some kind of timing issue. When I for example stall the
execution by adding a

```
(wait-until #(= 1 2) 10000)
```

between the two functions the field gets filled. A simple

```
(Thread/sleep n)
```

does not work in this case. Why is Selenium not filling in the form correctly?

Comment: Is the form generated with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes it is. Actually it's clojurescript. The form is loaded through an ajax request from the server. I get a vector of vectors from the server and render it through hiccup in the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDriver and AJAX calls usually require tweaking the wait settings. You should try setting [implicit-wait](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#implicit-wait) to something bigger than 0 (which is the default). Another option would be to use [wait-until](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#wait-until) and a predicate that checks for the presence of the elements.

Comment: I already set implicit-wait to 3 seconds. I will try checking for each element seperately and then update my question.